# Database Design of Result Management of a School

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am designing school management system in which a school have multiple `branche`s and a `branch` has multiple `class`es and a `class` has multiple `section`s, `student` can enroll only in one `section`. I want to maintain result of students and its history of the result so that I can get student's performance. My designed database for maintaining result have columns as under

`BranchID`,`ClassID`,`SectionID`,`SubjectID`,`StudentID` and `TestID` as foreign keys

If I make this design then too many duplication will occur for storing result of each all tests of each subject of each student of respective class of specific section.

1) Is it a good design ?

1.1) If yes, then kindly tell me on which columns indexing is required ?

1.2) If no, please proposed me a better design?

Comment: Are you saying you have one table in your database with those columns?

Comment: I would suggest you start by carefully reading this article - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Design/72054/ It is written with SQL Server in mind, not MySQL, but the basic principles are same for any DBMS

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @RyanWilson No, I have numerous tables I am taking their primary(ID's) to assign to main table as foreign keys other related tables are as under:

School
Branch
Class
Teacher
Student
Test
Admin